# How to put Emacs into magit's commit edit mode from emacsclient

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I have set Git's "core.editor" config to "emacsclient" and have an Emacs session running with a server started. When I run "git commit" from a terminal, it opens a new buffer in my Emacs as expected, but this buffer is always in "fundamental mode". It used to open in whatever mode that magit uses to edit commit messages but this is a new computer and I am just not sure how all the pieces work together. It's not even clear to me what mode magit is using since it's a collection of minor modes not a major mode. So I'm a bit stumped how to fix this.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Magit uses `git-commit mode` to write commit messages. You can check if that is installed

Comment: That's not what I see when I commit from magit, I think it's in text mode with a bunch of minor modes. This is what describe-mode says: "Enabled minor modes: Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Auto-Fill Blink-Cursor
Diff-Auto-Refine Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Git-Commit
Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit Ido-Everywhere Line-Number
Magit-Auto-Revert Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Shell-Dirtrack Tooltip
Transient-Mark With-Editor"

Comment: Hmm this is weird. I was going to add that "git commit mode" didn't seem to be installed or available, but it actually is available only AFTER I start using magit in a particular session

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what `magit` uses, but `vc` should use a variant of `log-edit-mode`.

```
(require 'log-edit)
(require 'vc-git)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'" . vc-git-log-edit-mode))
```

It's really weird that I need the `require`s; there's either a bug in Emacs or I'm doing something weird (though it doesn't seem the least bit weird to me).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found solution here:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17733/12560

Actually I just had to add

```
(global-git-commit-mode)
```

to my init and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to [@bingen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38208327/3249688), if you are a `use-package` user,

```el
(use-package git-commit
  :init
  (global-git-commit-mode)
  )
```

which works even with lazy loading turned on:

```el
(setq
 use-package-always-defer t
 use-package-always-ensure t
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that `git-commit.el` has not been loaded yet and/or that the server has not been started yet.  These things have always already been taken care of when you commit from Magit because in order to do so, Magit has to be loaded and doing that involves loading `git-commit` and starting the server.

You can add the following to your `~/.emacs` or `init.el` to enable `git-commit-mode`:

```lisp
(require 'git-commit)
(server-mode)
```

Reference: [`git-commit-mode` isn’t used when committing from the command-line](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/git_002dcommit_002dmode-isn_0027t-used-when-committing-from-the-command_002dline.html)